# Printing a column to a text using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a shell script to print a column to text file :

```
#!/bin/bash  
for i in `seq 1 1 174492`;  
do  
for j in `seq 0 100 14000`;  
do  
echo "$j" >> "depth"  
done  
done
```

But the program is taking too long. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You could use `bash`'s own range expansion `{start..end..delta}`

Comment: I would write a C program. Is that an option?

Comment: Well if it takes less time, I would wouldn't mind using it. Thank you all.

Comment: I think it will take you longer than 8 seconds to write and compile a short C program, instead of using the awk solution I posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use built-in brace expansion rather than calling `seq`, and redirect the whole outer loop rather than opening and closing the file once per iteration of the inner loop:

```
for i in {1..174492}  
do  
    for j in {0..14000..100}  
    do  
        echo "$j"  
    done  
done >> "depth"
```

Now your overhead is the loops themselves, so if that's still not fast enough for you, then use a faster language:

```
awk 'BEGIN { 
    for (i = 1; i <= 174492; ++i) 
        for (j = 0; j <= 14000; j += 100) print j
}' >> depth
```

I tested this on my system and it took 8 seconds, whereas the shell loop took over 2 minutes.

Comment: Well, I got bored of waiting for the shell loop (stopped after ~1 minute), whereas awk took 8 seconds.

Comment: Well I think then `Awk` is what should be recommended may be? Wondering why it is faster than range expansion!

Comment: I suspect that the slow thing is the shell processing the instructions themselves, rather than the expansions (`echo {1..174492}` takes hardly any time at all).